# Python subprocess inside a Docker container says a custom package is installed but can't import it

Tags: python, docker, pip, subprocess, setup.py

I'm trying to run a python package as an ENTRYPOINT to a Docker container which installs another package with setup.py then runs something inside. I use subprocess to install the second package. The output from terminal says that the second package got installed after the subprocess, but I couldn't import the second package. Here's the code:

```
        my_tar = tarfile.open('user_package.gz')
        package_main_directory=os.path.commonprefix(my_tar.getnames())
        my_tar.extractall('/')
        my_tar.close()

        os.chdir('/'+package_main_directory)

        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'develop'])

        for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules():
            if ispkg:
                print("Found submodule %s (is a package: %s)" % (modname, ispkg))

        from module import function
```

I keep getting the error "no module name module" although the output from terminal says that the package is installed. pkgutil.iter_modules() isn't showing the second package name either. I tried pip install as well and it gives the same error. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Could you install the package in the Dockerfile instead?  Do you call something like `os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)` to run the `CMD`; and then does the Python interpreter that (re)launches have the module correctly imported?

Comment: add to your docker file "ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:path to main folder"